# E580 wont boot if usb-C dock is connected

Tags: boot, thinkpad, 19.10, usb-c

After upgrading to 19.10 I experience something odd:

If my **USB-C Dock** has been connected to my **ThinkPad E580** the system stuck on log-In screen and the fan starts to spinning very fast ( and sometimes it shuts down after some secs ), ( sometimes it logs successfully but most of the times it will NOT )

But if I disconnect the dock it will log in very fast and without any problem.